# Google Analytics 4 "set" method not working

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-4

Basically a dupe [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71605774/google-analytics-4-gtag-js-set-command-not-adding-data-to-events), but that one's still unsolved, so I'll ask again:

I'm trying to set up GA4 (I am *not* using Google Tag Manager). According [to this doc](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference#set), the following two pieces of code should accomplish the same thing:

1)

```
gtag('event', 'testing', {'foo':'x'});
```

2. 

```
gtag('set', {'foo':'x'});
gtag('event', 'testing');
```

But only the first one works as expected. With the second one, the property "foo" is ignored - as if I never made the "set" call. So what's going on?