# Triggered the Google Analytics: GA4 Configuration in GTM, but the updated config fields are not being received in GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

[image: ga4 in debugview]
[image: gtm in debugviw]

I triggered the config event in GA4 manually, but some values were not collected at that time. After the values were collected, I tried to retrigger the config event in GTM, but I found that the config event was not triggered in GA4.

What I really want is to set some global propery that I can get in pageview event.... Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, GA4 has a setting called ignore duplicated configuration.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

GA4 sneak-deployed a change where it makes the gtag library to ignore subsequent config calls by default. You can change that though.

Take a look at this for more details: [can GA4 custom dimensions be updated after the initial 'config' call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76177242/can-ga4-custom-dimensions-be-updated-after-the-initial-config-call?rq=2)