# GA4 - gtag set behaviour

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, universal-analytics

Using GA we could set dimensions using `set`:

```
ga ('set', 'ua_dimension1', 'dimensionValue');
```

And this dimensions would be applied to the rest of the calls.

But using GA4's `set` like this:

```
gtag('set', {'ua_dimension1': 'dimensionValue'});
```

It does nothing, and the dimension isn't added to the rest of the calls...

When I set the dimension using `config` it does work:

```
gtag ('config', 'GA4_KEY', { 'ua_dimension1', 'dimensionValue' });
```

But it overrides all previous parameters that i setted to `config` before... Is there a way to set dimensions using `config` without overriding the previous `config` calls?

What im missing? In the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference#set) they say that `set` has to work as it does before, but it isn't.

I already registered this dimensions on my GA4 account, and waited 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, gtag is not ga. Analytics.js used to be a great library with a lot of useful functionality. Gtag is missing that complexity, instead, it's capable of doing a wide range of things unrelated to Google Analytics.

Read this on the set problem: [Google Analytics custom dimension not working: gtag set() method issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73870122/google-analytics-custom-dimension-not-working-gtag-set-method-issues)

You either set the dimension with the config, or you set them in events. Or, of course, you stop using gtag.js directly and use it via GTM as per best practices.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, i already read this, but i can't find any answer related about the override of the `config` using more than one call.

Comment: You have to solve it outside of the gtag library. It has no solution for you.

Comment: I would suggest you to work with dataLayer.push using Google Tag Manager.