# Moved to GA4, but now the custom dimensions are not getting any data

Tags: google-analytics-4, gtag.js

I have recently updated an application from UA to GA4. In UA, the application was using a few custom dimensions, so I updated the code around it using gtag.js to have it compatible with GA4.

The custom dimensions are created in a master page _layout.cshtml and expectation is all the pages that uses it, all tracked events will pass the custom information to the custom dimensions.

This is how it is set up
in _layout.cshtml

```
<script async src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=<my gtag id>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.dataLayer=window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag() { dataLayer.push(argumnts);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', '<my gtag id>');
gtag('set', {'dimension1':'getUserId()'});
gtag('set', {'dimension2':'getUserName()'});
gtag('event', 'page_view');
</script>
```

Then in one of the page, that has included this _layout.cshtml, I captured a click event for GA4

```
scope.onclickAction= function(){
gtag('event', 'click'{
'event_category': 'myEventCategory',
'event_label': 'an event label',
'event_value': <some int value>
});
}
```

Now in GA4 dashboard > Reports > Engagement > Events, I can see my event listed, but when I'm adding my custom dimensions, they both have (not set) as value.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: don't use set. It's meant for GTM. gtag documentation is misleading in this regard. We went more thoroughly through it here: [Google Analytics custom dimension not working: gtag set() method issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73870122/google-analytics-custom-dimension-not-working)